# Building ROS Node which contains OpenCV in Netbeans 8.0 leads to undefined references

Tags: c++, opencv, netbeans, netbeans-8, ros

I am trying to compile the code for a ROS (indigo) node which contains OpenCV 3.0 code. This node of my colleague compiles perfectly fine in Eclipse on Ubuntu 14.04 but it throws following errors when I try to compile it in Netbeans (8.0.2):

```
Linking CXX executable devel/lib/lsvo/tft_estimation
CMakeFiles/tft_estimation.dir/src/tft_test.cpp.o: In function `drawMatches(std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, std::allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > > const&, std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, std::allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > > const&, std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, std::allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > > const&)':
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0xbcf): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0xc6a): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0xc96): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0xcb7): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0xd52): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0xd7e): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0xd9f): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0xe3a): undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0xe66): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0x1157): undefined reference to `cv::line(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0x11e6): undefined reference to `cv::line(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0x1276): undefined reference to `cv::line(cv::_InputOutputArray const&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0x1445): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0x146a): undefined reference to `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0x1474): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0x1535): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0x1551): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0x1572): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
tft_test.cpp:(.text+0x1596): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [devel/lib/lsvo/tft_estimation] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/tft_estimation.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have the feeling that it is somehow a problem of linking the openCV libraries correctly but I don't know how to do that because the "Linking" menu is gone in Netbeans 8.0.